# strstr cannot find substring but buffer contains the value

Tags: c, stm32f4discovery, strstr, sim800

I was trying `UART` using `STM32F407V6T6` and `CubeMx`.

My `UART` is working fine. The problem I'm getting while comparing the buffer: I am using `strstr()` to check that my buffer contains valid substring or not.

Here is the code:

```
uint8_t buff[10];

int main(void) {
    HAL_Init();
    SystemClock_Config();
    MX_GPIO_Init();
    MX_USART2_UART_Init();
    Green_Blink(100);
    Orange_Blink(100);
    Blue_Blink(100);
    Red_Blink(100);

    __HAL_UART_ENABLE_IT(&huart2, UART_IT_TC);
    __HAL_UART_ENABLE_IT(&huart2, UART_IT_RXNE);
    HAL_Delay(1000);

    while (1) {
        HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart2, (uint8_t *)"AT\r\n", 5);
        Orange_Blink(100);
        HAL_Delay(1000);
        HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, buff, 10);
        buff[9] = '\0';
        if (buff[6] == 'O' && buff[7] == 'K') {
            Green_Blink(1000);    //Blinks
        }
        if (strstr((char*)buff, "OK")) {
            Red_Blink(1000);      //Doesn't blink
        }
        Clear_Buffer((char*)buff);
    }
}
```

Here what I am doing is I have connect my `GSM Module Sim800` and I send `AT`. After debugging my code I found that `buff[6] = 'O'` and `buff[7] = 'K'`. And while checking that I could blink the led.

```
        if (buff[6] == 'O' && buff[7] == 'K') {
            Green_Blink(1000);    //Blinks
        }
```

But when I try function `strstr()` It doesn't return anything.

```
        if (strstr((char*)buff, "OK")) {
            Red_Blink(1000);   //RED LED DOENS'T Blink
        }
```

At first I thought my array `buff` is not ending with `\0`. So I did this

```
     buff[9] = '\0';
```

But nothing changed.

Any suggestions why it's not working with `strstr()`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is it has some zeros before 6 & 7?

Comment: How long is the string according to `strlen()`?  If there'e a null byte before the `OK` bytes, then `strstr()` won't find the `OK` — it stops at the first null byte.

Comment: No it contains 0x0A and 0x0D. Total response in debug is like this A T 0x0D 0x0A 0x0D 0x0A O K 0x0D 0x0A.  the hex are `\r` and `\n`.

Comment: Have you included `string.h`?

Comment: Yes i have included `string.h`

Comment: Does `if (strstr((char*)buff + 6,"OK"))` "work"?

Comment: In this case some of the information you provide is incorrect. How do you check the content of the buffer to claim there is no zeros in it?

Comment: By the way, you say that `buff[9]` is `\0`, but in above comment it is `0x0A`.

Comment: Or. The `Red_Blink` simply doesn't work.

Comment: try  if (strstr((char*)buff,"OK")) Green_Blink(1000); , and check does green led is blinking? maybe there is an issue with red led?

Comment: I wonder... is `Green_Blink` even returning? Or just some dead loop?

Comment: I have used user defined `strstr()` function n now its working. How this even possible??

Comment: "*How this even possible?*" "This" what?

Comment: Yes all the led's are fine as i am blinking them before entering the while loop

Comment: `strstr()` of `string.h` is not giving the right ouput but while i used a code https://www.robomart.com/blog/user-defined-function-strstr/      from this link. Everything is working fine.

Comment: Wow. Don't ever use anything from that page. The code is horrible.

Comment: I would advice to see what you have in the buffer before char 6 and 7

Comment: I predict that buff is not null terminated

Comment: Please check the question i have edited the whole question as that question was not even helpful for others

Comment: Please don't change your question to an entirely new one, especially if it ends up invalidating an existing answer.

Comment: Sourav: If you are editing a new question on top of an old one because you've been question banned, then ping me at `@halfer` and I'll find some resources to help you unblock your account.

Answer (score 1):

From your observations and analysis, `buff` does contain `OK` at offset `6` and is null terminated at offset 9.

If `strstr` does not find `OK` in `buff`, a possible explanation is `buff` may contain another null terminator before offset 6 and `OK` is not present before this null terminator.

`buff` is initialized to all bits 0, so any element that is not changed is a null terminator. Is it also possible that `HAL_UART_Receive_IT` store null bytes into `buff`? null bytes are sometimes used as padding in serial transmissions.

It is also possible that the C library function `strstr` does not work on your target platform. I once had an inexplicable streak of bugs from faulty string functions on embedded ST platforms with their toolset.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain?

Comment: Do you still worry? Some people get much more satisfaction when DV than when they UV. Of course your answer is correct and the buff **must** contain zero before the char `O`. BTW OP has a hardware debugger built int in his board and it is sortable in 30 seconds - it enough to hover over the buff when debugging.

Comment: @P__J__: unless the C library `strstr` does not work, which is very well possible given the target.

Comment: `strstr` works very well in all gcc based ARM toolchains I know. So it is very unlikely `strstr` to do not work. I do ARM uCs programming for years and I have not found any faulty `strstr` implementations. BTW I UVed.

Comment: @P__J__: as I said, it did happen to me once on an embedded ST platform with their gcc based toolset. It might have been caused by a bogus configuration, but if was very upsetting to realize the origin of the problem: using custom replacements for `strcpy` and `strcat` fixed the problem.

Comment: Seeing the posted code (and no debug attempts ) I more suspect that the rewritten `strstr` works just incidentally :), and only in this case

Comment: @P__J__: I agree that the code from robomart.com is horrible, lacks indentation, has a innate function name, uses `NULL` for `'\0'` and is downright incorrect for `strstr("", "")`, but it seems to work for the OPs case.

Comment: Please check the question i have edited the whole question as that question was not even helpful for others

Comment: The comment from @sourav is now out of date, since it refers to the question being replaced by a completely new one. We don't allow that here, so it has been rolled back.