# After using strstr() the substring also transmitted via uart

Tags: c, strstr, stm32f4, sim800

I was trying `UART` using `STM32F407V6T6` and `CubeMx`.

As I have posted some problems with `strstr()` function. Here is some new problems.

Here is the code:

```
char rxBuff[10];
int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  Green_Blink(100);
  Orange_Blink(100);
  Blue_Blink(100);
  Red_Blink(100);
  while (1)
  {

        HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart2,(uint8_t*)"hello\r\n",10);
        HAL_Delay(1000);
        Orange_Blink(100);
        if (strstr(rxBuff,"hi"))
        {

        }
   }
}
```

Here what i am doing is I am transmitting `hello\r\n` using Transmit interrupt. After transmitting I am checking for certain values like `hi` in `rxBuff[10]`.

In this particular code i am not receiving anything I just created the buffer and checking if it contains `hi` or not.

Note that while transmitting I am just sending 7 bytes of data. But in `HAL_UART_Transmit_IT()` at place of size I am giving 10.

`HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart2,(uint8_t*)"hello\r\n",10);`

After flashing this code to my stm32 I can see in terminal various output like

> > hello\r\nhi

If I change the txt from `hi` to some other thing like planets, then the output will be like

> > hello\r\npl

But when I give the perfect size like this

`HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart2,(uint8_t*)"hello\r\n",7);`

I get the actual output i should be getting

> > hello\r\n

Transmitting the data via UART and finding if substring is present in some buffer is totally different tasks.

Any suggestions why this is happening?

P.S: Basically my project is with GSM MODULE SIM800c and STM32f407VGt6 
I want to send various AT commands from the stm32 and check the response so that I can work accordingly.

Previously I have tried this project with AVR series mcus where I could send sms,receive a particular sms,send data to server using post and get methods and everything worked completely fine.

After moving to ARM I am not getting how STM32 is behaving.

Comment: Please don't repost [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51829039/uart-transmit-and-strstr-gives-wierd-outputs)

Answer (score 5):

This has nothing to do with the `strstr` function. You are telling `HAL_UART_Transmit_IT` to go read beyond the end of the array (string literal) `"hello\r\n"`. What it will find there is anyone's guess, it's undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

On this line:

```
HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart2,(uint8_t*)"hello\r\n",10);
```

you are telling it to transmit 10 bytes. `"hello\r\n"` is only 7 bytes + NULL terminator, so it also sends the next thing in memory, in this case the first 2 bytes of that other string that you're using in `strstr`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `"hello\r\n"` string was placed into some *read-only* area of your program. This is the same for your `hi` or `planets` strings. Compiler put these strings one after another in memory (or better to say, linker) and since you did not specify exact memory length of your string, you printed out if valid are.

You were lucky that both strings were in memory one after another.

`h e l l o \r \n \0 p l a n e t s`.

Since you printed `10` characters, you printed `hello\r\n`, followed by `NULL termination` and then `pl`, together `10` characters.

Lesson learned: Do not access to memory you are not allowed to. You were allowed to access only `strlen("hello\r\n") + 1` bytes.